# Integration tests for TextWebSocketHandler

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration, spring-websocket

I searched for integration tests in spring for websockets with socket handler but i couldn't find.
How can i write tests to check if connection is established and if message.sendMessage() actually send message. Can someone please show me example of how can I achive that?

WebSocketConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ComPortProperties.class)
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private final Message message = new Message("text");


    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketHandler(message), "/data");
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(ComPortProperties ComPortProperties){
        return args ->{
            System.out.println(ComPortProperties);
        } ;

    }

}
```

SocketHandler:

```
@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketHandler.class);

    Map<WebSocketSession, Boolean> sessions = new HashMap<>();

    private Message message;

    public SocketHandler(){

    }

    public SocketHandler(Message message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        InetSocketAddress clientAddress = session.getRemoteAddress();

        logger.info("Accepted connection from: {}:{}", clientAddress.getHostString(), clientAddress.getPort());

        sessions.put(session, true);

        while (sessions.get(session)){
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(message.sendMessage()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {

        logger.info("Connection closed by {}:{}", session.getRemoteAddress().getHostString(),
                session.getRemoteAddress().getPort());
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, status);

        sessions.put(session, false);

    }
}
```

message:

```
public class Message {
    private String text;

    public Message(String text){
        this.text = text;

    }

    public String sendMessage(){
        return text;
    }

}
```

Comment: There should be a known bug that will fail the tests no matter what. This is because it fails while preparing the application context with the socket handler. This is what I knew, just look if they fixed this on some recent releases